# Ajax method is getting a 405 error when I try to consume a WCF Service

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, cors

I have an enabled CORS WCF Service and the other hand, I have a Rails app where I'm trying to make a request via Ajax (I manually ran this at Browser Debug Console):

```
function GetBookId(){

$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url:  "http://localhost:8369/BookService.svc/Book/3",
   contentType: "json",
   dataType: "json",
   xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: false 
    },
   headers: "GET",
   //processData: true,
   success: function (data) {
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
    var objData = $.parseJSON(jsonData);
    var bookId = objData.BookId;
    var isbn = objData.ISBN;
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
}
```

The WCF Service is running at port 8369, and my Rails app is at port 3000, so browsers complain about Cross-Domain or Cross-Origin preflight requests with a Error 405. As I said, the WCF Service is enabled to receive GET, POST, PUT and DELETE methods:

```
...
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
...
```

After debugging or watching the Request Headers, I found when I use the `GetBookId()` method, Is sending `OPTIONS` as Request Method instead a GET or POST, so get that

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:8369/BookService.svc/Book/3. Response for preflight
>   has invalid HTTP status code 405

In Firefox Developer Tools I edited the Request Header as a GET Method and send it again. The Response was a 200. So I guess that problem is that. The jQuery ajax method is sending a wrong Method, How can I send it properly with this method?

Comment: no...OPTIONS is normal preflight, it means server isn't handling it and returning all the CORS headers. If OPTIONS doesn't have the headers, the main request isn't sent

Comment: After some research i found a way to enable OPTIONS preflight in WCF Service. https://praneeth4victory.wordpress.com/2011/09/29/405-method-not-allowed/
However, I'm not sure is the right solution, because it relies in creating an additional Global.asax.cs file instead using the Web.config xml file